# Can't open ics-openvpn with android studio in mac

Tags: android, ics-openvpn

I clone OpenVPN project in [ics-openvpn](https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn). And then I install NDK, CMake, swig(4.0.1), update git ... follow [doc/README.txt](https://github.com/schwabe/ics-openvpn/blob/master/doc/README.txt) and I open it with Android studio after that.
But when open the project with Android studio I can't see another package in the project.

**Here is my result:**

[image]

How I can fix it to see all the packages and build the project?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

- if you want to devlope on this project follow this steps:

  1. clone the repo
  2. create a new empty project
  3. click on File then new then import module and go to the repo that you download. open it and choose **main** folder
  4. build the project
  5. open terminal from the android studio and type `cd main/cpp`  or the name that you name it to this module and download this sub modules :
- git submodule add https://github.com/schwabe/openvpn.git
- git submodule add
  https://github.com/schwabe/platform_external_openssl.git
- git submodule add https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls.git
- git submodule add https://github.com/schwabe/openvpn3.git
- git submodule add  https://github.com/lz4/lz4.git
- git submodule add  https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/asio.git

  6. run this commands on terminal :

  git submodule init

  git submodule update

  7. go to build.gradle  for openvpn module and change the following :

  `id("com.android.application")` to     `id("com.android.library")`

  8. copy this snipt of code that exist in `build.gradle` for the library and paste it in your `build.gradle` inside android script :

```
    flavorDimensions("implementation")
    
    productFlavors {
        create("ui") {
            setDimension("implementation")
            buildConfigField("boolean", "openvpn3", "true")
        }
        create("skeleton") {
            setDimension("implementation")
            buildConfigField("boolean", "openvpn3", "false")
        }
    }
```

9. add the module in the dependency in your `build.gradle` :

`implementation project(path: ':your-module-name')`

10. sync the project and it is done  :-)

**NOTE: if you can not see the module files click on the gradle on the right of android studio and left-click on the openvpn module and choose refresh Gradle project.**

I hope it can help someone.

Comment: Thank you so much but when I import module with main folder it so error :  Specify location  of the gradle of android eclipse project

Comment: ok the error indicate that you are importing the module in the wrong way

Comment: In Android Studio: File -> Import Module -> open ics-openvn -> select main. What is wrong?

Comment: ok i tried it my self and no error message show up i dont know what is wrong

Comment: try to open main module as project

Comment: @MohammadSommakia Thank you for these amazing instructions. I have a question about step 5.  I have imported the module as `vpnLib`. Do I download the submodules into `myApp/vpnLib/src/main/cpp`, or into `myApp/vpnLib/`?

Comment: Hello @Houman 
You need to download the submodules into 
myApp/vpnLib/src/main/cpp
You are welcome 
please upvote the answer if it helps you

Comment: @MohammadSommakia And when I do step 10, I get one error when building the project: `myApp/vpnLib/build.gradle.kts:152:9: Unresolved reference: applicationVariants`. What do I do here please?

Comment: Hmmm, I can't be sure what is the error exactly
I need to see the code so I can fix it because last time I build the project year ago :)

Comment: @MohammadSommakia You have so much experience with this. Do you think you could start a new project just to confirm if these instructions still work, please? That would be amazing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230262/discussion-between-mohammad-sommakia-and-houman).